# Convert datetime ISO8601 C# - Could not convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a C# backend that receives a json with the modification date of a file generated by an application that uses JUCE libraries.
It turns out that the modification date was sent in the default
"2022-10-20T16:16:27.000-03:00" with a period (.) separating the milliseconds.
After some updates to the operational system the information started to come separated by a comma (,).

With this the backend will return
"modifiedDate": [
"Could not convert string to DateTime: 2022-10-20T16:16:27,154-03:00. Path 'modifiedDate', line 4, position 49."
]

While debugging the project I noticed that conversion error occurs when reaching the Controller.

```
        [HttpPost("create")]
        [RequireStation]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AudioFileViewModel>> CreateFile([FromServices] IAudioFileService serviceAudioFile, [FromBody] CreateAudioFileWithMediaInfoAndPlaylistAsObjectCommand model)
        {
...
}
```

What is the best way to handle this error? I tried to replace the string in the set of the model class, but was unsuccessful.

Is it possible to handle it directly at startup or in some middleware?

Comment: What is the `,154-03:00` part? I've never seen that part. Are you sure it's valid ISO8601?

Comment: Hello, it should be the milliseconds.
Before I was getting .000-03:00, with (.) dot, now it is with (,) comma.
I need to treat this string in the backend to change the comma to the dot.

Comment: As far as I can tell (and [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) seems to confirm it in section 5.6), ISO 8601 uses the literal dot ("."), not the culture-specific decimal separator, so the JUCE library is wrong. It wouldn't be much of a standard if it allowed for culture-specific separators. Don't create garbage to allow garbage.

Comment: Current ISO 8601 allows for either dot or comma, preferring comma.

Comment: In that case, RFC 3339 is narrowing to a literal dot, just as it narrows other parts of ISO 8601. [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) specifies RFC 3339 format, not full ISO 8601. The client shouldn't produce a comma.

Comment: Assuming the client is going to return a comma whether or not it's in agreement with standards, a custom model binder is likely necessary.

Comment: Just some information that might be useful,
The JUCE library is unchanged since 2020.
In versions compiled until mid-June this year it kept returning the string with the dot as separator.
However, after compiling it on another computer, this time with Windows 11, this same code started to generate the string with a comma (,).
Would it be correct to adjust the backend in order to not have to change all the clients at the first moment?